# How do I convert 12Vdc solar to AC?

Tags: solar-cell, inverter

We are using 12V DC solar power at home, and I want to use it for home appliances. Can you suggest what should I have to use for this? At present we are using 4 (12V) lights and one DC fan. Now we want to use this source for AC fans also.

Answer (score 3):

Normally the way to convert 12v DC to 120v AC is to use a inverter like [this one](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3537166), designed for automobiles.  I don't know if your solar device would have enough power to run this or not.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use an Inverter to run AC devices off of your solar panels. There are several kinds of inverters and if you have large panels that you plan to run constantly such as off-grid you will want a pure sine wave inverter. However as tcrosley stated you did not supply us with sufficient information on your setup as to the amount of current your panels output.

If your panels output 12 Volts at 10 Amps and you used a theoretically perfect inverter (no losses) you will only be able to drive a load at 120 Volts 1 Amp. However there will be conversion losses. Be careful using inductive loads with cheap equipment as you have a possibility of frying your inverter.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

For solar applications you've got to design or buy special solar inverters which can track the  Maximum Power Point of the Panel (Vmp and Imp). A normal inverter would not do much justice to solar powered applications as the voltage of solar panel varies all round the day.

Comment: Normally, when you answer an old question, it's not anymore for the OP but for leaving useful knowledge; so try to make the answer more complete, explaining a bit more MPPT and the function of the inverter.

Comment: bro, do you think entire MPPT can be described here. Google, get some books, study ... you dont get everything that easy in life.

Comment: EEhi easy! I know what it is, and I'm not asking you to explain everything. Just add some content, because now the answer gives less information than previous ones. Maybe a very conceptual block scheme, or whatever you want.